# Magento 2: How to disable module programmatically on mode change to production?

Tags: magento2, php, developer-mode

I've created a custom module for developer mode only. So, I want to create functionality that disables module automatically when mode change from developer to production.

Answer (score 0):

This is where composer comes in handly:

Add the module to the require-dev part of your composer.json. 
In your **production system** you get all packes WITHOUT dev: `composer install --no-dev`
In your **local enviroment** you just `composer install` to get all packes which are located in the require-dev part.

Fore more information read here: composer require dev version